# jquery.ajax() using json data from mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have a page that creates json data and encodes it. If I go to the page the output looks like this:

```
{"hail":
    [
        {"date":"140714","time":"1646","size":"100","city":"3 ESE HOUSTONIA","county":"PETTIS","state":"MO","lat":"38.88","lon":"-93.31","other":"(EAX)"},
        {"date":"140714","time":"1649","size":"100","city":"HUGHESVILLE","county":"PETTIS","state":"MO","lat":"38.84","lon":"-93.3","other":"US POSTAL WORKER WITH A QUARTER SIZED HAIL REPORT. (EAX)"},
        {"date":"140714","time":"1742","size":"175","city":"7 NNE COOLIDGE","county":"HAMILTON","state":"KS","lat":"38.14","lon":"-101.96","other":"(DDC)"}
    ]
```

I am then trying to use

```
function addMarker(){
    alert("success 1");
    var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : '/data/hail',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(response) {
                alert("SUCCESS");

                    hail = response.hail;

                    // loop through places and add markers
                    for (h in hail) {

                        //create gmap latlng obj
                        tmpLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( hail[h].lat, hail[h].lon);

                        // make and place map maker.
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: tmpLatLng,
                            title : hail[h].city
                        });

                        // not currently used but good to keep track of markers
                        markers.push(marker);

                    }

                }
        })

    setAllMap(map);
}
```

The first alert goes off, but the second alert is never called. I have on my main index page the includes for jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If `alert("SUCCESS");` isn't appearing, then the request isn't successful. This can mean an unexpected response status code like `500` or that jQuery had issues parsing the full response. Are any errors being logged to the Console? Does the request appear successful under Network? Try adding an `error` callback and inspecting the `textStatus` and `errorThrown` (2nd and 3rd arguments).

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski I just did not post all the output. Just the first few lines. It has the final bracket. I am checking errors now

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski using firefox I see that it shows the request for the page is bad giving me a 404 error. Using request method get. I am just echoing the data like this from the page: echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski it looks like the content type is wrong. Firefox is showing the content type is html and the script is looking for JSON

Comment: A `404` status implies the `url : '/data/hail'` isn't right. The `text/html` type is probably just due to the server serving a default error page. Are both the page making this request and the `hail` resource hosted on the same domain and port? The details of the request under Network may show the full URL used with `/data/hail`. Does that match the address you used when requesting it directly?

Comment: Yes they are, the json page is just two levels down

Comment: I changed the url to just the full url and it seems to be working now. At least the alert is being thrown. If you submit an answer I will select it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the lines

```
var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''
    });
```

Is giving an error. There must be some error on the browser console.

The Ajax call is correct though.

Comment: If I move the first alert after the info window it still loads. Nothing loads in the json call. Firefox is showing my data page is returning the wrong content type

Comment: Also if I put an alert after the json call it works as well. It has to be in the Ajax call

Comment: @shinjuo - You are right then. In that case, it has to be that the format of the json data is incorrect. You could try validating the data here http://jsonlint.com/ ?